# Selenium error when switching to a frame: NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to switch to this frame

[image]

However, I kept getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yaoweiqi/PycharmProjects/learnselenium/test1.py", line 29, in <module>
    browser.switch_to.frame('layui-layer-iframe6')
  File "/Users/yaoweiqi/PycharmProjects/learnselenium/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py", line 89, in frame
    self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_FRAME, {'id': frame_reference})
  File "/Users/yaoweiqi/PycharmProjects/learnselenium/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/yaoweiqi/PycharmProjects/learnselenium/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.1 x86_64)
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.
Following is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from wait_element import wait_element

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/yaoweiqi/Downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get('http://47.99.113.178/index.html')

wait_element(driver=browser, xpath='//input[@class="user-aqm-input"]', action='input', keys='***')
wait_element(driver=browser, xpath='//input[@class="user-user-input"]', action='input', keys='***')
wait_element(driver=browser, xpath='//input[@class="user-pwd-input"]', action='input', keys='***')
wait_element(driver=browser, xpath='//button[@class="user-submit determine"]', action='click')
try:
    wait_element(driver=browser, xpath='//img[@class="updataclose"]', action='click')
except:
    print('notice already closed')

wait_element(driver=browser, xpath='//*[@class="icon-jiahao"]', action='click')
wait_element(driver=browser, xpath='//*[@class="housing-type"]', action='click')

time.sleep(5)

frames = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
browser.switch_to.frame('layui-layer-iframe6')
```

Comment: There is missing `l` and the number should be 1, not 3.

Comment: And you should post code and html as text, not as image.

Comment: Thanks, but I've changed my code but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: @Jade, which error ?

Comment: Is this frame inside another frame?

Comment: @Jade What are the _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Answer (score 2):

As per the HTML to *switch to the desired frame* you need to use *WebDriverwait* for the *frame to be available and switch to it* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='layui-layer-iframe'][src^='fangyuan']")))
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@id,'layui-layer-iframe') and starts-with(@src,'fangyuan')]")))
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

you are doing wrong, `ayui-layer-iframe6` it must be `layui-layer-iframe6`
try this,

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_name("layui-layer-iframe6"))
```

and again come back to main window use,

```
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

as traceback gives `NoSuchFrameException` so putting wait would also work `WebDriverWait()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I've changed my code but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Read carefully my answer i have told you to write `browser.find_element_by_name("layui-layer-iframe1")` not just `layui-layer-iframe1`

Comment: I tried your code. Now I'm getting this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"layui-layer-iframe6"}

Comment: `switch_to.frame` receives `id` and `name` as parameter. It isn't necessary to use `find_element_by_`

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder, the name of the iframe might **change** with the number of clicks.

Here is an example:

```py
for num in range(1, 2):
    frame_id = "layui-layer-iframe" + str(num)
    browser.switch_to.frame(frame_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. I used this code:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="layui-layer-iframe6"]'))
```

Comment: Actually `browser.switch_to.frame('layui-layer-iframe6')` means totally the same as `browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="layui-layer-iframe6"]'))`. I can hardly believe that this line could solve your issue